# Passing down @FocusState to another view

Tags: swiftui

I was wondering how would u be able to pass down a @FocusState to another view. Here is some example code.

```
struct View1: View {
  enum Field {
    case username, password
  }

  @State var passwordText: String = ""
  @FocusState var focusedField: Field?

  var body: some View {
    // How would I be able to pass the focusedField here?
    View2(text: $passwordText, placeholder: "Password")

    //TextField("Password", text: $passwordText)
        //.frame(minHeight: 44)
        //.padding(.leading, 8)
        //.focused($focusedField, equals: .password)

    // How would I be able to add the commented code above to View2
  }
}

struct View2: View {
  @Binding var text: String
  let placeholder: String

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .frame(minHeight: 44)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            // How would I be able to add this
            //.focused(binding: , equals: )
        if text.count > 0 {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

How would I be able to pass it down to View2. Or is there a better way to reuse a custom textfield? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: For me it's working without passing down the state. It's inheriting automatically

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pass its binding as argument, like

```
struct View1: View {
  enum Field {
    case username, password
  }

  @State var passwordText: String = ""
  @FocusState var focusedField: Field?

  var body: some View {
    View2(text: $passwordText, placeholder: "Password", focused: $focusedField)
  }
}

struct View2: View {
  @Binding var text: String
  let placeholder: String
  var focused: FocusState<View1.Field?>.Binding     // << here !!

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .frame(minHeight: 44)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            .focused(focused, equals: .password)     // << here !!
        if text.count > 0 {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering how would I be able to to set the focusedField to nil when a button is clicked on view2. It says its immutable in the View2 and was just wandering how would I be able to do it.

Comment: To set the focusedField in View2, wouldn't you change the `focused.wrappedValue` ?

Comment: This works but how do I make the preview work with such a weird variable? var focused: FocusState<View1.Field?>.Binding ?

Comment: @erotsppa - did you find a way to use such variable in previews .. ? if yes, could you please share ?

Comment: @erotsppa Add `@FocusState static var focus: Field?` to the preview and inject as a binding using `$`

Comment: Use "FocusState<Bool>().projectedValue" (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75430571/how-to-set-a-value-for-focusstate-in-swiftui-preview)

Comment: How would pass the FocusState binding to a public init of View2? with a default value?

Comment: Feels pretty strange to me, that `View2` has to know about `View1.Field`. What if you wanted to reuse `View2` somewhere else? Haven't found a great way of dealing with this besides fairly complex Generic Hashable structures.

Answer (score 22):

Storing `FocusState<Value>.Binding` does not seem to work for me

I got it working like this, which seems to behave just like how regular Binding works:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(text: $text, isFocused: $isFocused)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState.Binding var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField($text)
            .focused($isFocused)
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a simpler way to declare the binding in the child view than the way it is done in the accepted answer. However, if the child view has an `init` function then the syntax from the accepted answer is needed for the parameter.

Comment: Are you sure this statement is correct?  If you make the parameter of type `Binding<Foo>` instead of maybe using just `Foo`, I'm pretty sure you can pass it in as normal without that other syntax. I pass bindings through my own initializers this way all the time.

Comment: I like this one better since you can mutate the value in the child view.

Comment: This is nicer, too, because if you want to also reference the isFocused value or set it, you dont have to use a bunch of `.wrappedValue`