# How to set a value for @FocusState in SwiftUI Preview

Tags: swiftui, binding, preview

I'm passing a FocusState-property of a textfield to a childview. This works as expected. In this childview I want to get the preview working, however I can't seem to set a contant value for the Focusstate. Anyone ideas?

```
struct MainContentView: View {
@FocusState private var focusedField: Bool

    var body: some View { 
        ScoreView(focussed: $focusedField)
    }
}

struct ScoreView: View {
@FocusState.Binding var focussed: Bool

    var body: some View {
        someSubView(focussed: $focussed)
    }
}

struct ScoreView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ScoreView(focussed: ????????). <- here
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to set a constant for the state-property just like with @State boolean properties, but I get the message:

> Type 'FocusState.Binding' has no member 'constant'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should help `FocusState<Bool>().projectedValue`

```
struct ScoreView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScoreView(focussed: FocusState<Bool>().projectedValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Bool then it’ll require a value but if you use an Enum or other Hashable type for the FocusState, you can make it optional in your parent view and declare it the same way in your preview as:

`@FocusState static var focus: SomeHashable?`