# SwiftUI: Passing @FocusState in custom textfield class from parent class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have created a class for a TextField and I am trying to use @FocusState for my class. The requirement is to use this custom class in a parent view like below -

Here is the custom TextField class -

```
struct FloatingPlaceholder: View {
        
        @Binding var textfieldText: String
        @FocusState var hasFocus: Bool // need this to be optional.
        
        init(textfieldText: Binding<String>, focused: FocusState<Bool>? = nil) {
            self._textfieldText = textfieldText
            self.hasFocus = focused ?? // How to specify value here..??
        }
        
        var body: some View {
        
        TextField("Password", text: $textfieldText)
                            .focused(focused)
        }
    }
```

Then using this Custom TextField class in `Login` class-

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @FocusState var passwordFocused: Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
     FloatingPlaceholder(textfieldText: $viewModel.password, focused: $passwordFocused)
    
    }
}
```

This gives me an error -
`Cannot convert parent type 'FocusState<LoginAndRegistrationView.Field?>' to expected type 'FocusState<Bool>'`

And also crashes the `Preview` part.

Can anyone explain how can we use `@FocusState` properly and pass it to the custom class ? or is there a better way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141230/passing-down-focusstate-to-another-view.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this which worked for me

```
struct AppTextField: View {
   var isFocused: FocusState<Bool>.Binding

   ...
}
```

then use it like regular binding variable.