How to get @FocusState property to work when passed as a binding to TextField that's displayed on a .sheet?
I have the following simple code which places a Button on a View and when tapped, presents a TextField on a .sheet:
struct TestView: View
{
    @State private var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false
    @FocusState private var textFieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Button("Hello")
        {
            self.sheetIsPresented = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$sheetIsPresented)
        {
            TestViewSheet(textFieldIsFocused: self.$textFieldIsFocused)
        }
    }
}

struct TestViewSheet: View
{
    @State private var userInput: String = ""
    @FocusState.Binding var textFieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            Text("Name:")
            TextField("Enter name", text: self.$userInput).focused(self.$textFieldIsFocused).onChange(of: self.textFieldIsFocused)
            {
                print("textFieldIsFocused")
            }
        }
    }
}

When the TextField is activated and the keyboard appears, the .onChange of is not occurring and "textFieldIsFocused" is not being printed to the console. However, when I don't pass textFieldIsFocused as a binding and instead list it as @FocusState, the code works fine. How can I get it to work when I pass textFieldIsFocused as a binding?

does this SO post answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141230/passing-down-focusstate-to-another-view/78513735#78513735

@workingdogsupportUkraine interesting, will implement later and see thx.

@workingdogsupportUkraine nah didn't work :(

Do you actually have a good reason for wanting to pass in the FocusState as a binding, instead of defining it locally in the sheet view? If it's for the purpose of speeding up the keyboard reveal, this post might help.

@BenzyNeez yeah this is a simplified version of what's in my app where I have a generic that needs a bunch of bindings passed into it. will check out that link, thanks.
